# Accessing i3-wm JSON response obj from i3ipc-glib through gir_ffi gem

Tags: ruby, glib

I am looking to control my i3 window manager through a ruby script. The [existing gem](https://github.com/badboy/i3-ipc) is no longer maintained, and it is recommended that you use the [i3ipc-glib](http://dubstepdish.com/i3ipc-glib/) C library in conjunction with [gir_ffi](http://rubydoc.info/gems/gir_ffi/0.7.5/) to replicate its function. (The gir_ffi gem "creates bindings for GObject-based libraries at runtime based on introspection data provided by the GObject Introspection Repository (GIR) system").

I can successfully use it to send commands thusly:

```
require 'gir_ffi'

namespace = 'i3ipc'
GirFFI.setup namespace

i3 = I3ipc::Connection.new(nil)
i3.command 'focus right'
```

I do not however receive the JSON reply outlined in the [i3 IPC documentation](http://i3wm.org/docs/ipc.html). Instead I get a `GLib::Slist` ([doc](http://rubydoc.info/gems/gir_ffi/0.7.5/GLib/SList)) object (or in some cases `I3ipc::Con`).

```
2.1.2 :108 > command = i3.command('focus left')
 => #<GLib::SList:0x000000019f70d0 @struct=#<GLib::SList::Struct:0x000000019f7058>, @element_type=I3ipc::CommandReply>
2.1.2 :111 > command.class
 => GLib::SList
2.1.2 :112 > command.class.superclass
 => GirFFI::StructBase

2.1.2 :094 > workspaces = i3.get_workspaces
 => #<GLib::SList:0x00000001ab6ae8 @struct=#<GLib::SList::Struct:0x00000001ab6ac0>, @element_type=I3ipc::WorkspaceReply> 
2.1.2 :095 > workspaces.class
 => GLib::SList 

2.1.2 :035 > tree = i3.get_tree
 => #<I3ipc::Con:0x000000013c4a78 @struct=#<I3ipc::Con::Struct:0x000000013c51f8>> 
2.1.2 :036 > tree.class
 => I3ipc::Con 
2.1.2 :037 > tree.class.superclass
 => GObject::Object 
2.1.2 :038 > tree.class.superclass.superclass
 => GirFFI::ObjectBase
```

How can I access the original JSON response?

Comment: Looking at the documentation for i3ipc-glib I don't think it makes the raw JSON response available. Is there something in the response you need you can't obtain from the objects the library builds from it?

Answer (score 0):

You may try an improved [i3ipc](https://github.com/veelenga/i3ipc-ruby) gem:

```
>> require 'i3ipc' #=> true
>> i3 = I3Ipc::Connection.new
=> #<I3Ipc::Connection:0x000000009fc068 @protocol=#  <I3Ipc::Protocol:0x000000009fc040 @socketpath="/run/user/1000/i3/ipc-socket.1043", @socket=#<UNIXSocket:fd 9>>>
>> command = i3.command('focus left') #=> [#<I3Ipc::Reply:0x007fbf90145940 @data={:success=>true}>]
>> command[0].to_h #=> {:success=>true}

>> workspaces = i3.workspaces
=> [#<I3Ipc::Reply:0x007fbf900e77f0 @data={:num=>1, :name=>"1 Browse", :visible=>true, :focused=>false, :rect=>#<I3Ipc::Reply:0x007fbf900ffd78 @data={:x=>1366, :y=>20, :width=>1920, :height=>1060}>, :output=>"VGA1", :urgent=>false}>, #<I3Ipc::Reply:0x007fbf900e6e68 @data={:num=>0, :name=>"0 Term", :visible=>true, :focused=>true, :rect=>#<I3Ipc::Reply:0x007fbf900e7458 @data={:x=>0, :y=>20, :width=>1366, :height=>748}>, :output=>"LVDS1", :urgent=>false}>]
>> workspaces[0].to_h #=> {:num=>1, :name=>"1 Browse", :visible=>true, :focused=>false, :rect=>{:x=>1366, :y=>20, :width=>1920, :height=>1060}, :output=>"VGA1", :urgent=>false}
>> workspaces[0].visible
>> workspaces[0].name #=> "1 Browse"
```

This is not actually a json, but a parsed hash. But there is a way to get an original string response with low level class:

```
>> protocol = I3Ipc::Protocol.new #=> #<I3Ipc::Protocol:0x007fbf9c08aee0 @socketpath="/run/user/1000/i3/ipc-socket.1043">
>> protocol.connect #=> #<UNIXSocket:fd 10>
# 1 means get_workspaces message
>> protocol.send(1) #=> 14
>> response = protocol.receive(1)
=> "[{\"num\":1,\"name\":\"1 Browse\",\"visible\":true,\"focused\":false,\"rect\":{\"x\":1366,\"y\":20,\"width\":1920,\"height\":1060},\"output\":\"VGA1\",\"urgent\":false},{\"num\":0,\"name\":\"0 Term\",\"visible\":true,\"focused\":true,\"rect\":{\"x\":0,\"y\":20,\"width\":1366,\"height\":748},\"output\":\"LVDS1\",\"urgent\":false}]"
```